# Copy dir from old copies itself inside the new dir if it already exists

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

So i'm trying to copy files and folder from one directory to another one. And the basic function works, it copies everything but if the new folder already exists then it will copy the old folder inside the new folder and not just the content.

Basicly if the folder doesnt exist, then it will be created and the content of the old folder will be copied to the new one.
BUT
If the new folder already exists then the it copies the entire folder into the new one, not just the content.

Here is a whole example you can try.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Windows,
  ShellApi;

function CopyDir(const fromDir, toDir: string): boolean;
var
  fos: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@fos, SizeOf(fos));
  with fos do
  begin
    wFunc := FO_COPY;
    fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
    pFrom := PChar(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(fromDir) + #0#0);
    pTo := PChar(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(toDir) + #0#0);
  end;
  Result := (0 = ShFileOperation(fos));
end;

var
  dirFrom, dirTo: string;

begin
  try
    dirFrom := 'C:\UserTemp\FolderToCopy';
    dirTo := dirFrom + '_OLD';
    CopyDir(dirFrom, dirTo + '\'); //<-- this creates the folder with right content inside
    CopyDir(dirFrom, dirTo + '\');// <-- this instead of overwriting it will add FolderToCopy inside FolderToCopy_OLD
    writeln('ok');
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      readln;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

My expected result is to have the same content ovewritten. so if i copy "FolderToCopy" to "FolderToCopy_OLD" i expect to find just the content of "FoldertoCopy" inside "_old". INSTEAD what i'm having when the "_old" already exist is "FolderToCopy_OLD/FolderToCopy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it should be, because that is what you are asking `SHFileOperation()` to do - copy a folder into another folder.  To copy just the *contents* of a folder and not the folder *itself*, set `pFrom` to `'<folder>\*'` instead of `'<folder>\'`:

```pascal
pFrom := PChar(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(fromDir) + '*'#0#0);
```